# Fetch type is set to lazy, but it still hibernate sends the second request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Although fetch type is lazy, hibernate for some reason sends the second request and fetches the lazy one.
I have been dealing with this problem for a few days for some reason I don't understand. I tried some ways on the internet, but unfortunately I couldn't fix it, I would be very grateful if you could help me by looking at my code.

**User Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username", length = 50)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_friends" , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id"))
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Set<User> friends = new HashSet<>();

}
```

**User Service**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService implements ICrudService<User> {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User findById(Long id) throws Exception {
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new Exception("Kullanici Bulunamadi"));
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User create(User user) {
        return repository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

**User Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable Long userId) throws Exception {
        return userService.findById(userId);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public User saveUser(@RequestBody User user){
        return userService.create(user);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
    public void deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long userId){
        userService.delete(userId);
    }
}
```

I use JpaReository as repository in service

And the output of "/users/all" looks like this

**Output**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "testUser",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "password": "verystrongpasword",
        "friends": []
    }
]
```

**This is the hibernate sql format**

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.password,
        u1_0.username 
    from
        users u1_0
Hibernate: 
    select
        f1_0.user_id,
        f1_1.id,
        f1_1.email,
        f1_1.password,
        f1_1.username 
    from
        user_friends f1_0 
    join
        users f1_1 
            on f1_1.id=f1_0.friend_id 
    where
        f1_0.user_id=?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When fetch type for property is `Lazy`, the data is retrieved on demand - when the getter for the property is invoked. `User` is serialized as json when the response is sent, and json libraries normaly to this using the getters - `getFriends()` is invoked reflectively by the underlying library.

The solution (and good practice) is to use a `DTO` for response/request, not entities.

Comment: Up vote for suggestion  `DTO` instead of `Entity` in request/response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is triggered by `Lombok` `@Data` annotation, because under the hood it use `@ToString` that by default use all fields of `class` to create it.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1.Create your own `toString()` method, `Lombok` will then backoff generating a toString.

2.Add the `@ToString` annotation and exclude all the lazy and bi-directional fields using `@ToString.Exclude`.
In your case somethig like next one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@ToString
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username", length = 50)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_friends" , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id"))
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<User> friends = new HashSet<>();

}
```

More deep details about it and other cases you could find [Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities](https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/) a good article by **Marten Deinum**.